# Not able to install zookeeper in windows

Tags: apache-zookeeper

When i am executing `zkServer.cmd` via below command:

```
D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin>call "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2"\bin\java "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\.." "-Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE" -cp "D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\build\classes;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\build\lib\*;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\*;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\*;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\conf" org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg"
```

Output:

`2020-02-22 22:07:42,378 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@136] - Reading configuration from: D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg
2020-02-22 22:07:42,384 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
2020-02-22 22:07:42,384 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
2020-02-22 22:07:42,385 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
2020-02-22 22:07:42,387 [myid:] - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@116] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode
2020-02-22 22:07:42,487 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@136] - Reading configuration from: D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg
2020-02-22 22:07:42,487 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@98] - Starting server
2020-02-22 22:07:42,512 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.14-4c25d480e66aadd371de8bd2fd8da255ac140bcf, built on 03/06/2019 16:18 GMT
2020-02-22 22:07:42,512 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:host.name=LAPTOP-78H8U6PB
2020-02-22 22:07:42,517 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.version=13.0.2
2020-02-22 22:07:42,518 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2020-02-22 22:07:42,519 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2
2020-02-22 22:07:42,519 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.class.path=D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\build\classes;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\build\lib\*;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\zookeeper-3.4.14.jar;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\jline-0.9.94.jar;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\netty-3.10.6.Final.jar;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\conf
2020-02-22 22:07:42,520 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;.
2020-02-22 22:07:42,520 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\erdiv\AppData\Local\Temp\
2020-02-22 22:07:42,521 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2020-02-22 22:07:42,523 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.name=Windows 10
2020-02-22 22:07:42,524 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.arch=amd64
2020-02-22 22:07:42,525 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.version=10.0
2020-02-22 22:07:42,525 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.name=erdiv
2020-02-22 22:07:42,526 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.home=C:\Users\erdiv
2020-02-22 22:07:42,526 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.dir=D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin
2020-02-22 22:07:42,534 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@836] - tickTime set to 2000
2020-02-22 22:07:42,534 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@845] - minSessionTimeout set to -1
2020-02-22 22:07:42,534 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@854] - maxSessionTimeout set to -1
2020-02-22 22:07:42,962 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ServerCnxnFactory@117] - Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory
2020-02-22 22:07:42,964 [myid:] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@89] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181`

the process gets stuck and zookeeper is not started

Also, when i do  `./zkServer.cmd start`, following is the output:

`D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin>call "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2"\bin\java "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\.." "-Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE" -cp "D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\build\classes;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\build\lib\*;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\*;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\lib\*;D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\conf" org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg" start
2020-02-22 22:14:58,220 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
2020-02-22 22:14:58,223 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
2020-02-22 22:14:58,225 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
2020-02-22 22:14:58,232 [myid:] - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@116] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode
2020-02-22 22:14:58,338 [myid:] - ERROR [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@57] - Invalid arguments, exiting abnormally
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "D:\zookeeper\zookeeper-3.4.14\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerConfig.parse(ServerConfig.java:61)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:86)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:55)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:119)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:81)
2020-02-22 22:14:58,340 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@58] - Usage: ZooKeeperServerMain configfile | port datadir [ticktime] [maxcnxns]
Usage: ZooKeeperServerMain configfile | port datadir [ticktime] [maxcnxns]`

Answer (score 0):

> the process gets stuck and zookeeper is not started

It's not stuck. It started and is waiting on connections

By the way, Java 13 might not work with Zookeeper 3.4.x